# RM -rf Files only

Tags: php, linux

Only delete file and not  folder with rm -rf

I have a db, which I loop through the file_path and check if file_exist

If file does not exist. I execute

```
rm -rf $db_value
```

But sometime the db_value got empty value, which will make my script delete the folder instead.

How do I ensure what I deleting is 100% not directory, I only want it to delete file.

Comment: Why do you use the command line to delete a file? You could use `unlink()`. You could also check with `is_file()` if the target is a file. And maybe you should check before you do anything anyway if the database value isn't empty.

Answer (score 3):

Try in this way:

```
find /path_to_files/ -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```